# how to add a horizontal scroll bar for h:selectManyListbox

Tags: jquery, css, jsf

My `h:selectManyListbox` has a vertical scroll bar. But how do I add a horizontal scroll bar.

Any method (**css, jquery**) is fine with me.

```
<h:selectManyListbox   id="scriptslistId" value="# {ModifyScriptBean.selectedItems}"  
     style="height:350px;">
<f:selectItems value="#{ModifyScriptBean.selectItems}" />
   </h:selectManyListbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your style attribute, just add the "overflow: auto" as follows:

```
<h:selectManyListbox   id="scriptslistId" 
     value="#ModifyScriptBean.selectedItems}"  
     style="height:350px;overflow: auto;">
```